# The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server

Tags: magento

The error appears on my custom grid, where I do 'select all' for all my records (more then 3000) and try to go to the next grid page.
As I can see, all my IDS are set into internal_import param of URL

```
/internal_import_ids/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...
```

How can I put this internal_import_ids to POST, rather then to URL?

internal_import_ids declared in massaction section

```
...
$this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('import_ids');
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions I found, is to use AJAX. With AJAX Grid works nicely.

```
public function __construct()
{
    ...
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}
```

So, my problem is solved. But if somebody will found the solution without AJAX - it will be nice to see it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a thread] about the max URL length.([What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url))

> Short answer - de facto limit of 2000 characters.

And here is [more info from Boutell](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) in their FAQ under the heading of “What is the maximum length of a URL?”:

> Extremely long URLs are usually a mistake. URLs over 2,000 characters
>   will not work in the most popular web browser. Don't use them if you
>   intend your site to work for the majority of Internet users.

Comment: I need to move internal_import_ids, that are params of massaction, somewhere, so the result will be POST send, not URL